# Is closed convex set with finite number of extreme points convex polyhedron

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, polyhedra, convex-geometry

I have this simple question related to convex set and convex polyhedron. As the content in the title, it's basically my question:

> Is closed convex set with finite number of extreme points convex polyhedron

If not, can you please give me some hint to find the counter-example of that statement? Thanks a lot. I really appreciate

Comment: What is a polyhedron?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It should be convex polyhedron. In wikipedia, "convex polyhedron is any point set that is the intersection of a finite number of half-spaces"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You additionally need that your set is bounded, otherwise it may have too few extreme points:

- any convex, closed cone has only one extreme point
- For any closed, convex $C$, consider $C \times \mathbb R$: no extreme points.

If your set is bounded, it is (assuming that the ambient space is finite-dimensional) compact. By Krein-Milman, the set is the convex hull of its extreme points, hence, a polyhedron.

Comment: Of course "convex hull of a finite set" includes things that it seems to me would at best be described as _degenerate_ polyhedra; for example do we really want to call a line segment in $\Bbb R^3$ a polyhedron? {Of course}^2 the definition "intersection of finitely many (closed) half-spaces" also includes degenerate polyhedra (for a few seconds I thought that that segment was not the intersection of finitely many half spaces, but of course it is...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: *Polytopes* are defined as convex hull of a finite set of points - and the only difference is that polyhedrons might be unbounded. And both definitions include "degenerate" sets. In fact, a line segment in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a non-degenerate one-dimensional polyhedron, that is embedded in a three-dimensional space.

Comment: Well fine then. You're saying I need to know the definitions, eh? I'll have to think about that. interesting concept, heh...

Comment: People wrote whole book about convex polytopes, so it seems to be an interesting topic :)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Can you suggest some good books about those topics. They are really interesting to me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @leducquang I wouldn't know, sorry. Ask gerw; if that doesn't work you might post a reference-request.

Comment: @leducquang: Some standard references concerning (convex) polytopes are Grünbaum's "Convex polytopes" and Ziegler's "Lectures on Polytopes".

Comment: @gerw: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, I will take a look at those books.

Comment: @gerw I have a question, if I choose $C$ is a unit ball in $R^2$, then $C \times \{0\}$ = $\{(x_1,x_2,x_3) | x_3 =0, x^2_1+x^2_2 \le  1\}$ has infinite extreme point, that is $\{(x_1,x_2,x_3) | x_3 =0, x^2_1+x^2_2 =  1\}$. Hence, $C \times \{0\}$ is not a convex polyhedron although it is a closed convex. May I can find an example a closed convex which has finite extreme point then it is a convex polyhedron.

Comment: @FactorY: I had a typo in my answer, it should be $C \times \mathbb R$. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @gerw, thank you very much, I think I have my answer